# convert variable as :symbol and pass?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, carrierwave, symbols

Im trying to pass a function variable to carrier wave as a symbol to no avail, how could I do this correctly?

Like so:

```
    image_tag @profile.photos.first.file_url(:size)
```

My function:

```
  # Get avatar in correct size
  # Display or return default image
  def get_avatar(id, size)

    this_size = size.to_sym
    @profile = User.find(id).profile rescue nil
    image_tag @profile.photos.first.file_url(this_size)

  rescue
    image_tag ("/assets/avatars/img_#{size}.png")
 end
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If the size is not a string, you will need to convert first.

Try this:

```
this_size = size.to_s.to_sym
```

Or skip that line altogether and use this:

```
@profile.photos.first.file_url(:"#{size}")
```